# Chromecast sender app from Chrome on Android failing

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm building a Cast app with a chrome sender and custom HTML/CSS/JS receiver. While it works correctly from desktop chrome, I've noticed that I can't connect via the Android Chrome app.

With Android, when clicking the Cast button and selecting the correct receiver device in the Popup, nothing happens (my listener for SESSION_STATE_CHANGE is not called). After clicking the button again, my session listener says:

```
{type: "sessionstatechanged", 
session: null, 
sessionState: "SESSION_START_FAILED", 
errorCode: "invalid_parameter"}
```

At first, I thought my setup was incorrect, but after looking at [the official chrome sender app](http://googlecast.github.io/CastVideos-chrome-material/) and following the same steps as above, I noticed a similar problem with a different error code:

```
Request session failure: 
{"code":"invalid_parameter",
"description":"Already requesting session",
"details":null}
```

In the above case the visual indicator starts it's 'active' state on first click, but there's no change/activity otherwise it just stays in that state.

This was working before, so I know this is a relatively new issue (at least since Feb, possibly sooner). I also know since it's working on desktop, there's nothing wrong with the setup per se -- but it's still failing for Android.

Any help or feedback here would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after updating my Android phone (missed an update this morning) it seems to be fixed.

EDIT:
Turns out, it was due to the restart. So as a patch, restarting your mobile device will reset your Chrome and allow it to send correctly.